# Google Colab :"Is there any way to stream video using webcam and work on that?"

Tags: computer-vision, google-colaboratory, face-detection, conv-neural-network

In colab, I want to do a facial expression model on live streaming video. But I don't know how can I do this. I can get a source about video record and the link is [here.](https://github.com/emilyxxie/colab_utils_and_snippets/blob/master/video_webcam_snippets.ipynb) But I want to work on live video streaming in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, colab cannot access your web cam in real time. However, if you have already recorded video, then it is easy.

```
#!pip install deepface
from deepface import DeepFace
DeepFace.stream(db_path = "C:/facial_database", source = "my_video.mp4")
```

It will apply face recognition and facial attribute analysis (age, gender and emotion). If you store facial images in the path C:/facial_database, then it will look for the identity here for detected faces.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment Google Colab has included in it's `Code snippets` section (Insert/Code snippets) the `Camera Capture` snippet:

> Camera Capture
>
> Using a webcam to capture images for processing on the runtime.

```
from IPython.display import display, Javascript
from google.colab.output import eval_js
from base64 import b64decode

def take_photo(filename='photo.jpg', quality=0.8):
  js = Javascript('''
    async function takePhoto(quality) {
      const div = document.createElement('div');
      const capture = document.createElement('button');
      capture.textContent = 'Capture';
      div.appendChild(capture);

      const video = document.createElement('video');
      video.style.display = 'block';
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true});

      document.body.appendChild(div);
      div.appendChild(video);
      video.srcObject = stream;
      await video.play();

      // Resize the output to fit the video element.
      google.colab.output.setIframeHeight(document.documentElement.scrollHeight, true);

      // Wait for Capture to be clicked.
      await new Promise((resolve) => capture.onclick = resolve);

      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
      canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
      canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0);
      stream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
      div.remove();
      return canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', quality);
    }
    ''')
  display(js)
  data = eval_js('takePhoto({})'.format(quality))
  binary = b64decode(data.split(',')[1])
  with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(binary)
  return filename
```

---

```
from IPython.display import Image
try:
  filename = take_photo()
  print('Saved to {}'.format(filename))
  
  # Show the image which was just taken.
  display(Image(filename))
except Exception as err:
  # Errors will be thrown if the user does not have a webcam or if they do not
  # grant the page permission to access it.
  print(str(err))
```